# How to find out what type of linked server is it?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to find out whether a certain linked server is SQL SERVER or INFORMIX? Is their a way to find this out. I looked at sp_linked_servers however I don't want to rely on SRV_PRODUCT column because this is an entered field. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT provider FROM sys.servers;
```

These specify the driver used which will tell you the linked server type

`Ifxoledbc`/`MSDASQL` vs `SQLNCLI`/`SQLOLEDB` for example

I don't have an Informix server to hand of course so you may need other columns too.

Note MSDQSQL is the generic ODBC. But, it isn't `SQLNCLI`/`SQLOLEDB` so it must be Informix be a process of elimination